# Automatically generate DbContext from Database like LINQPad does

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, linqpad

Is there any way to do what LINQPad does with the `UserQuery` class? You just provide a connection and it automatically generates everything from scratch.

It's really useful!

Comment: EF6 or EF Core?

Comment: Theres a Visual Studio Extension called reverse poco generator. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonHughes.EntityFrameworkReversePOCOGenerator does that help?

Comment: @DavidG EF Core, but if it's for both it would be awesome.

Comment: BTW, in Visual Studio there is a template under "Add\New item...\Data" called "ADO.NET Entity Data Model". It generated a DbContext and all the clases needed by it. Is it similar to what LINQPad does? It also autogenerates the classes in the DB.